# How can I reduce TTFB (time to first byte) response?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, centos

I am running a PHP project on my local Ubuntu system using nginx. On my local system, when I send a request to *127.0.0.1*, it returns 100ms at first, and then returns 10ms at the second, third, and all requests. When I upload to my second server with centor using nginx, it returns 100ms for all requests including the first one. What is happening with my local system? Is there config?

Answer (score 0):

TTFB depends a lot on the distance of the user from the web server thats serving the content. So it will always be a lot lower locally since the latency is almost 0. As for why is it lower on subsequent requests locally, i could only guess, could be caching.

Comment: When a request is sent for the first time (local machine), all subsequent requests are less from any other users such as CURL, Chrome or anywhere (10ms). my guess is a cache too, but only for the request and not for the content. I do not know what to look for? Are there any settings for Nginx or anythisng else?

Comment: here are some tips for what you can do https://www.criticalcase.com/blog/how-to-optimize-time-to-first-byte-ttfb.html . But generaly speaking 100ms is great for a production environment and i dont think you could get anywhere near the 10ms you want on prodcution. Take a look at any site google or whatever other site nobody has a ttfb lower than 100ms.

Comment: You are right marac990. My requests are sending to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) from local and I am talking about some configs that I do not know where are?! The configs resolve it after first request that meaning subsequent (somthing like cache)